# Is there any functional difference between Array.replicate and Array.create in F#?

Tags: arrays, f#

I was refactoring some code and noted that some coders used `Array.replicate` and other `Array.create` when initializing an array with repeatedly the same value. The signatures of both functions are identical:

```
> Array.create;;
val it : (int -> 'a -> 'a [])

> Array.replicate;;
val it : (int -> 'a -> 'a [])
```

I also noted that both raise an `ArgumentException` on a negative `count` value, and both allow a count of zero. My gut tells me they are synonymous, but then I found this quote on [F# For Fun And Profit](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/list-module-functions/#5-creating-a-new-collection-of-known-size-with-each-element-having-the-same-value):

> *Array.create is basically the same as replicate (although with a subtly different implementation!) but replicate was only implemented for Array in F# v4.*

Is anybody aware of what differences exist, or are they, for all intents and purposes, aliases of one another (perhaps `replicate` was merely added for parity with `seq`)?

Comment: Per the source code, their implementations are indeed different: https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/array.fs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is equivalent and shouldn't perform any differently.

It seems like it was added to Seq and Array after List, so maybe for API parity. This is an old commit (2014) and a quick search through issues didn't turn out any one that would definitely explain the reasons for the change. https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/commit/173d833660767fd24d523d09f317179cc3c3f4b9

Comment: Thanks for the pointers to the source. The difference seems to be only in `Array.create` using a checked operator and `Array.replicate` not. Possibly this difference was unintentional and indeed shouldn't lead to any operational differences, as all operations are within array bounds.